# Angular messages validation file on blur

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

Is there a way to define the `ng-message` to show on blur, if I define it in an extra file?

For example I define following extra `ng-messages` error-file:

```
<p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
<p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
<p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-message="email">This needs to be a valid email</p>
```

What I want to do is, to show the `ng-message` only on blur, like:

```
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.name.$error" ng-show="userForm.name.$touched">
    ...
</div>
```

To use `ng-show` I need the form, input and event name. Can I somehow mock it in the extra error-file? For example with some placeholder, like when using Windows: `$DIR$` or something like that?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @developer0333 partly, I do not wanted to add extra help-block into the form

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't added anything besides `ngMessagesInclude`. Check it please.

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`ngMessagesInclude`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessagesInclude) directive as below:

```
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.name.$error" ng-show="userForm.name.$touched">
  <div ng-messages-include="your_path.html"></div>
</div>
```

Check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages) for more info.